# CentOS7 マウントできるファイルシステムがありませんと表示される

Tags: centos

OS(CentOS)のインストールをしたいのですが、
物理マシンを用意して、
DVD-RをBUFFALOのHDDにセットし、
CentOS7を書き込もうとしてますが、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

となります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何が原因なのでしょうか。
検索して解決策を探ってますが原因特定に辿り着けません。
ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記 SONYのVAIOでもBurnというアプリを使ってDVD-Rに書き込みの処理をしましたが、
書き込みが終わった瞬間に、「セットしたディスクは、このコンピュータで読み取れないディスクでした」と表示されました。(CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.iso)という事は、DVD-RやHDDに原因はなく、iMacに原因があるのでしょうか。

Comment: 「物理マシン(iMac)を用意して、(CentOS の ISO image が書かれた)DVD-R を(Sony の DVD マルチドライブに)セットして、(iMac の)BUFFALO の HDDに、CentOS7を書き込もう(インストールしよう)としてますが」という事なのでしょうか？

Comment: iMacとは別に物理マシンを用意しています。iMacにBUFFAROのHDDを繋げ、DVD-Rをセットし、CentOS7を書き込もうとしています。

Comment: イメージはPCでブート可能なDVD用のものだと思われます。iMac(と言うかmacOS)では、マウントできないファイル形式でしかパーティションが切られていないのでしょう。うまく書き込めていればインストール対象のPCに入れて、DVD起動を行えば、インストーラが立ち上がるはずですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSを物理マシンにインストールしたいのであれば、マウントではなくISOイメージをDVD-Rなどの光学メディアに焼く必要があります。

**追記**
CentOSのISOイメージはDVDメディアに**ISOイメージとして焼く**必要があります。

[mac OS High SierraでISOファイルからDVDを作成する方法](https://nt-take.com/2017/12/11/post-351/)

よくある間違いは、ISOイメージをファイルとして焼いてしまうケースです。DVDにライティングを行った後、ディスクを再挿入してメディアの中身を確認し、ISOイメージ1つが見えているだけなら焼き方が間違っています。

Comment: 焼く処理を行った後に、マウントできるファイルシステムがありませんと表示されますが、書き込みに失敗したのとは別という事ですか。

Comment: 書き込んだ後に、DVD-Rを外付けHDDにセットすると、「セットしたディスクは、このコンピュータで読み取れないディスクでした」と表示され中身が見れません。ディスクユーティリティを見ると、HDDは認識していたので、iMacに問題があるという事でしょうか。

Comment: 「DVD-Rを外付けHDDにセット」が何を指しているのかが分かりません。物理的なDVDはHDDに挿入しようがないですよね？そもそも外付けHDDは何のために出てきているのでしょう。ISOイメージを保存しているだけ or CentOSのインストール先？

Comment: iMacでDVDを出し入れ出来ないので、iMacに外付けHDDを接続して、最終的にISOイメージをインストールしたいと思ってます。

Comment: 補足 SONY DVD RW AW-G540A Media USB 外部物理ディスク • マスター・ブート・レコードです。

Comment: 今ライティングしたDVDを挿入し、Finderを開いて、デバイスの欄にある書き込みをした「名称未設定DVD」を開くとCentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.isoのみ入っているのですが、焼き方が間違っていると認識したらいいでしょうか。