# DVD-Rがデスクトップには表示されるのに、ディスクユーティリティには表示されない

Tags: linux, centos, ハードウェア

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

DVDにiosイメージを書き込む為に、DVD-Rを外付けDVDドライブに挿入しましたが、
デスクトップには表示され、Finderやディスクユーティリティには表示されません。
一度電源を落とすと改善されるという記事があったので試しましたが治りませんでした。
何が原因なのでしょうか。

ディスクユーティリティに表示される方法ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご回答願います。

Comment: Macについて詳しくないのですが、貼られているキャプチャでは、ディスクユーティリティ上で「初期化前」として認識されているように見えます。(初期化していないので、容量等が表示されていないのは正常かと思います。)

Comment: [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/47477/2808)のリンク先にある「ブランクDVDをドライブに挿入する。」を行った状態がそれだと思うので、続けて手順2以降を実施してみてはいかがでしょうか。(それで何かうまく行かないことがあればあらためて質問追記すれば良いかなと)

Comment: ブランクディスクをmacに挿入すると、そのディスクをどうしたいのか選ばせるダイアログが表示されたハスですが、その時何を選びましたか? Open Finder(日本語版なら「Finderで開く」?)を選ぶとその状態になるはずです。ただしFinder上でそのディスクアイコンを開くと黒い帯の付いたDVD書き込み用の擬似ウインドウが開くはずですが?